# Jmeter REST API calls Listeners view result tree confusion

Tags: json, rest, api, jmeter, performance-testing

In Listeners view result tree in that sampler Result tab,we have different parameters like size in bytes,sent bytes,header size in bytes,body size in bytes. so peoples can explain each things difference.
[image]

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately this question is too general for SO: it very much depends on particular configuration in sampler itself, and jmeter.properties file, so answering it would require copy/paste the entire "Response size calculation" section from http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request. So I suggest reading the basics there first, and then asking more specifically if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

1. `Size in bytes` - size of the **response**, i.e. how many bytes you received from the server
2. `Sent bytes` - size of the **request**, i.e. how many bytes you sent to the server
3. `Headers size in bytes` - size of  the response [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
4. `Body size in bytes` - size of response body, basically the length of what you see in the `Response Data` tab.

   `Size in bytes` = `Headers size in bytes` + `Body size in bytes`

References:

- [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [JMeter Listeners - Part 1: Listeners with Basic Displays](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-1-basic-display-formats)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information,,, now i got some idea about it... Just i need one more information if you have any idea about it means plz suggest me.  Am Pushing REST API calls(POST Method), but i want to calculate amount of data i pushed to server, for that i used flexible file writer(sent bytes) to calculate it,  but vales from flexible file writer and sent bytes values are not matching. so which data is correct